Assistance requested with fixing a bash backup script for a Termux Linux Android tablet
BACKGROUND:
I have been endeavouring to update my Android tablet  with different versions of this script and even before I set my mind on realising this script in particular and have been at it for quite some time, but I have so far not been completely successful. It is almost there.
My Termux Linux userland environment is a bit of a legacy ecosystem. I have tried to set up my system well, but there are anomalies and inconsistencies. I have just been teaching myself and learning on the fly.
In executing earlier versions of this script, it kept on maxing out the memory of my microSD, but there should have been more than ample space. The backup directories would be hundreds of times larger than the size of the original source directories. I realised it was infinite loops caused by nested symbolic links and probably other reasons that I have not yet identified. This is the reason for the structure of the script and the excessive logging.
The problems are few (I hope):

A virulent unbounded variable in the backup_files array. I just haven't been able to fix it and I don't know why.
I had a lot of problems with terminating all the spawned processes. Some of them were really sneaky. Hence, the KILLSWITCH. But I just can't get it to work and I don't know why.

https://pastebin.com/QrHgCiQ4
Any assistance to help me bash this into shape would be most appreciated.

please add the code into your question as text, not as a link ... format as code for readability

Always paste your script into https://shellcheck.net, a syntax checker, or install shellcheck locally. Make using shellcheck part of your development process.

That pastebin has a lot of adds though. You can paste that script in here.

I ended up just using a lossless Tarball. Done. Backed-up!
